# Using return within for iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am writing a code that takes in a tuple of integer as intervals and outputs a range of alphabets. I could use some help on return statement.

```
>>> arrangement((5, 3, 11, 7))
'A-E F-H I-S T-Z'
```

Below is what I have written so far. The return statement seems to return only the last iteration of the loop:

```
def arrangement(numerical_representation):
    interval = ''
    step = 65
    for integer in numerical_representation:
        interval = chr(step) + '-' + chr(step + integer - 1)
        step += integer
    return interval

>>> arrangement((5, 3, 11, 7))
'T-Z'
```

With print statements I am able to go through all the iteration, but I can't seem to make them print in a single line with quotation marks on both ends.

```
def arrangement(numerical_representation):
    interval = ''
    step = 65
    for integer in numerical_representation:
        interval = chr(step) + '-' + chr(step + integer - 1)
        step += integer
        print(interval)

>>> arrangement((5, 3, 11, 7))
A-E
F-H
I-S
T-Z
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: `print(interval, end='')` would do the trick. Or in your case, it looks like you want `print(interval, end=' ')`

Comment: You are assigning/overwriting the value of `interval` in each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
def arrangement(numerical_representation):
    start = 65
    result = []
    for n in numerical_representation:
        result.append('{}-{}'.format(chr(start), chr(start+n-1)))
        start += n
    return ' '.join(result)

print(arrangement((5, 3, 11, 7)))
#A-E F-H I-S T-Z
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `+=` instead of `=`:

```
def arrangement(numerical_representation):
    interval = ''
    step = 65
    for integer in numerical_representation:
        interval += chr(step) + '-' + chr(step + integer - 1)
        step += integer
    return interval

>>> arrangement((5, 3, 7, 11))
'A-EF-HI-OP-Z'
```

---

An alternative, what about using [`yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)?

```
def arrangement(numerical_representation):
    interval = ''
    step = 65
    for integer in numerical_representation:
        interval = chr(step) + '-' + chr(step + integer - 1)
        step += integer
        yield interval

>>> ''.join([x for x in arrangement((5, 3, 7, 11))])
'A-EF-HI-OP-Z'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a list and append each interval to it. And at the end return the list

```
def arrangement(numerical_representation):
    interval = ''
    step = 65
    l=[]
    for integer in numerical_representation:
        interval = chr(step) + '-' + chr(step + integer - 1)
        step += integer
        l.append(interval)
    return " ".join(l)


arrangement((5, 3, 11, 7))
A-E F-H I-S T-Z
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `chr`, why not use `string.ascii_uppercase` and string indexing?
You can use `itertools.accumulate` to generate the cumulative sum of the indices

```
from itertools import accumulate
from string import ascii_uppercase


def generate_indices(groups):
    begin = 0
    for end in accumulate(groups):
        yield begin, end-1
        begin = end


groups = (5, 3, 11, 7)
result = " ".join(
    (f"{ascii_uppercase[begin]}-{ascii_uppercase[end]}")
    for begin, end in generate_indices(groups)
)
```

> ```
> 'A-E F-H I-S T-Z'
> ```